# Wireshark is not installed after apt-get install

Tags: debian, wireshark, apt

I installed wireshark with `apt-get`, but there isn't any executable under `/usr/bin` after I installed it:
[image]

I installed it before and for some reason I remove it manually (`sudo rm`). Now I try to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get reinstall wireshark
```